# WSDL File location in eclipse

Tags: service, web, wsdl, location

I am new to web services concepts and applications. I would like to take a look at the wsdl file, but I don't know where it is located. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl+Shift+R and give *.wsdl and select from the list

Answer (score 0):

when service is imported in eclipse wsdl file is usually placed under ./WEB-INF/wsdl